# ios - can showing a message cause a crash?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection

I have this code:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {         
     NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

     if ( error != nil )
     {
         // Display a message to the screen.
         UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"There was a server error getting your business plan. We use a remote server to backup your work." 
                    message:@"Please make sure your phone is connected to the Internet. If the problem persists, please let us know about this." 
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [message show];
```

but it executes when a NSUrlConnection returns from the server.  It creates a crash on rare occasions.  Is it possible? It seems like such a harmless piece of code.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the content of your message something that is pulled from said `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: Where is this code located? Is it placed within a delegate method specified by the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`?  If so therein lies the issue.  If you can post more sample code, it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @esqew no the content is just plain text.

Comment: Just posted a bigger code clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the NSURLConnection returning a result on some odd thread? I don't know, but I suspect that UIAlertView is only meant to work on the UI thread, since it starts with UI.

```
 (dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"There was a server error getting your business plan. We use a remote server to backup your work." 
                message:@"Please make sure your phone is connected to the Internet. If the problem persists, please let us know about this." 
            delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

     [message show];
 });)
```

Sorry, haven't compiled this, there's probably a typo in there somewhere.

Comment: the code is in the block that executes once the NSUrlConnection call is made.  Is it not advised to display that message there? How should I display things to the user correctly?

Comment: Sorry, can't write small enough here. See next answer!

Answer (score 1):

If it's entering the conditional block to display the error it's not because of the UIAlert, it's because the NSURLConnection encountered an error.  I would output to the console the error information so that you can see what the error is when it gets into these rare occasions and solve the issue with the NSURLConnection

Comment: Crashalytics gave this extra info about the error: Exception Type:SIGSEGVCode:SEGV_ACCERR

Comment: __36-[BusinessController viewDidAppear:]_block_invoke_0

Comment: But how would I refactor the code to make it safer and not crash?

Comment: When it errors, I would output the strings returned by `localizedDescription` and `localizedFailureReason` as specified in the NSError Class Reference to get to the bottom of why your NSURLConnection is failing.  Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, you are not  displaying the alertView in the main thread. All UI related code is need to be work on main thread.

I got a similar crash when I displayed the alertView on another thread.

You need to change the method like:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {         
     NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

     if ( error != nil )
     {
         // Display a message to the screen.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"There was a server error getting your business plan. We use a remote server to backup your work." 
                    message:@"Please make sure your phone is connected to the Internet. If the problem persists, please let us know about this." 
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

          [message show];
       });
     }
}
```

**or** change it like:

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {         
     NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

     if ( error != nil )
     {
         // Display a message to the screen.
          UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"There was a server error getting your business plan. We use a remote server to backup your work." 
                    message:@"Please make sure your phone is connected to the Internet. If the problem persists, please let us know about this." 
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [message performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntillDone:NO];

     }
}
```